# imported class with class-validator annotration is not validated by Validation pipe

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator

I have a simple nest controller with validation pipe decorator

```js
import {GetCatDto} from 'my-shared-lib'

@Controller('myController')
export class MyController {
  constructor(private readonly policyManagerService: PolicyManagerService) {}

  @Get()
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
  getCat(@Query() getCatDto: GetCatDto) {
    return this.catService.getcates(getCatDto);
  }
```

in the shared lib (imported using npm link) :

```js
export class getCatDto {
  @Expose({ name: 'cat_name' })
  catName: string;
}
```

if I send the following get request : `GET localhost:3000/myController?Cat-Name=mycat`
I don't get validation error.

BUT..
If I copy/paste the dto into my project (i.e in the same file as the controller). the validation works as expected.

at first I thought it might be be related [to this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/690) but my `tsconfig.json` includes the mentioned headers.

I'm using nest.js 8.0.0 and class-validator 0.13.2

Comment: change `http://localhost:3000/myController?Cat-Name=mycat` --> to `http://localhost:3000/myController?cat_name=mycat`

Comment: I wanted to give an example of something that violates the name as it is written in the "Expose" decorator

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the main issue was due to the fact that the `class-transformer` version in my shared lib was not **exactly** the same as it was in my service. once I straightened that up it worked as expected.
This is mentioned in [this](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/337) Github Issue